# Удаления файлов PHP

Tags: php, jquery, phpmyadmin

По нажатию на елемент хочу удалять файлы из бд и сервера, но получаю пустой ответ от сервера и ошибку:

```
status: 500,
responseText: "",
statusText: "Internal Server Error"
```

```js
$('#js-remove').click(function(){
       let id =  $(this).attr('data-id');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'remove.php',
            data: {'id': id },
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false,
            success: function (respond) {
                console.log('good');
                console.log(respond);
             },
             error:function(respond){
                console.log('bad');
                console.log(respond);
             }
        });
    });
    
//PHP

$connect_to_db = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_password)
or die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());

mysql_select_db($db_name, $connect_to_db)
or die("Could not select DB: " . mysql_error());

 $id = $_POST['id'];

$rmfile = mysql_query("SELECT img1,img2,img3,img4,img5,img6,img7,img8 FROM cars WHERE id = '$id'") 

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rmfile)) {
    foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
        unlink('../img/uppcars/'.$value.'.jpg');
    }
}
$remove = mysql_query("DELETE FROM cars WHERE id = $id");
mysql_close($connect_to_db);
```

```html
<button data-id="374esndas3had" id="js-remove">Delete</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибки 500 это ошибки на уровне сервера, советую посмотреть логи или сделать вывод ошибок в браузер (через php.ini, .htaccess или прямо в коде задать)

Проблем может быть много, от подключения к бд до наличия удаляемого файла на сервере

Файл перед удалением нужно проверить через file_exists() например

```
$rmfile = mysql_query("SELECT img1,img2,img3,img4,img5,img6,img7,img8 FROM cars WHERE id = '$id'")
```

Для начала попробуйте убрать '' у $id

Comment: [14-Feb-2019 21:02:32 Europe/Moscow] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'while' (T_WHILE) in .../remove.php on line 21

Comment: Синтаксическая ошибка, 21 строка

Comment: И на будущее для избежания уязвимостей кода всегда проверяйте пользовательские данные, которые попадают в ваш запрос, как минимум через mysql_real_escape_string()

Comment: ето я понял как исправить? while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rmfile)) {} //21 cnhjrf

Comment: $rmfile = mysql_query("SELECT img1,img2,img3,img4,img5,img6,img7,img8 FROM cars WHERE id = $id")

Comment: $rmfile = mysql_query("SELECT img1,img2,img3,img4,img5,img6,img7,img8 FROM cars WHERE id = $id"); Добавьте точку с запятой после этой инструкции.

Comment: [14-Feb-2019 23:35:06 Europe/Moscow] PHP Warning:  mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in .../remove.php on line 21